# Bounty not awarded, answer was accepted with 2 upvotes : iPad app

Tags: support, bug, bounty

My answer to a question was accepted several days before the bounty period ended. 
The answer also received two upvotes before bounty period ended.

But no bounty was awarded on expiration. What did I miss?

Here's the question:
[How to decrypt the file which encypted on different openssl's version and different os?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53519238/how-to-decrypt-the-file-which-encypted-on-different-openssls-version-and-differ/53568700#53568700)

Edit: After reading answer below, I discovered that this is a bug in Stack Overflow iPad app. It will not show bounty notice once it enters the grace period.

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes, however this looks like an actual bug on the Stack Overflow iPad app. It does not show that the bounty is still active when it enters grace period.

Comment: Look for the tag ios-app.

Comment: The downvotes likely come from people who didn't know you were using the app, looked at the question on main, saw right away it was in grace period and then figured you must have not done much research before coming here. So the downvotes are likely a mix of 'unresearched' and exasperation.

Comment: The "Goon Squad" culture in SO has been alive and kicking for quite some time.

Answer (score 5):

The bounty is still within its grace period and hasn't gone through the automatic award process yet. You'll receive the bounty whenever the grace period ends and the system processes the bounty removal, assuming the user hasn't returned to manually award it by then.

**Hint:** If the bounty notice still appears on the question, then the system hasn't attempted the auto-award yet.

Be patient. :)